# Leave only a single word in a txt

Tags: c, file, exec

I have this code in C, My argv[2] is the file passed by argument in the program call.

```
    int fd = open("stdout.txt",O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC,0666);
    dup2(fd, STDOUT);
    close(fd);
    execl("/bin/file","file",argv[2],NULL);
```

That checks the extension of a file and passes the output to a txt file. She returns an output in this style:

```
1212.gif: GIF image data, version 89a, 695 x 343
```

I need to check the output (stdout.txt) and leave only the part where the file type is. the file types I need to check are **PDF, GIF, JPG, PNG, MP4, ZIP and HTML.**

How can I leave only the extension part **(PDF, GIF, JPG, PNG, MP4, ZIP and HTML)** ?

I can use linux commands inside Exec.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `strchr()` to find the first `.` and copy to a new string

```
   int posCharoint = strchr('.');
   int posCharDoublePoint = strchr(':');
   char *newString;
   // malloc newString of posCharDoublePoint - posCharPoint

   int i = 0;
   while (posCharPoint < posCharDoublePoint) {
      newString[i] = string[posCharPoint];
      i++;
      posCharPoint++;
   }
```

If you want to use bash command, you can use `cut` :https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut